# How to convert list of intable strings to int

Tags: python, string, list, int

In Python, I want to convert a list of strings:

```
l = ['sam','1','dad','21']
```

and convert the integers to integer types like this:

```
t = ['sam',1,'dad',21]
```

I tried:

```
t = [map(int, x) for x in l]
```

but is showing an error.

How could I convert all *intable* strings in a list to int, leaving other elements as strings?

My list might be multi-dimensional. A method which works for a generic list would be preferable:

`l=[['aa','2'],['bb','3']]`

Comment: Note that `[map(int, x) for x in l]` will try to turn each string into a *list* of integers, character by character. You probably meant either `map(int, l)` or `[int(x) for x in l]`.

Comment: `[int(x) for x in l]` will throw `ValueError`s for non-numeric strings.

Comment: `map(lambda line: [int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in line.split(",")])` - note this does not account for negative integers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd use a custom function:

```
def try_int(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x
```

Example:

```
>>> [try_int(x) for x in  ['sam', '1', 'dad', '21']]
['sam', 1, 'dad', 21]
```

---

**Edit:** If you need to apply the above to a list of lists, **why didn't you converted those strings to int while building the nested list?**

Anyway, if you need to, it's just a matter of choice on how to iterate over such nested list and apply the method above.

One way for doing that, might be:

```
>>> list_of_lists = [['aa', '2'], ['bb', '3']]
>>> [[try_int(x) for x in lst] for lst in list_of_lists]
[['aa', 2], ['bb', 3]]
```

You can obviusly reassign that to `list_of_lists`:

```
>>> list_of_lists = [[try_int(x) for x in lst] for lst in list_of_lists]
```

Comment: @larsmans: Emh... I don't know... I was probably dazzled by the OP `map()`. I'll update the answer in a moment :)

Comment: I've been so bold as to do it for you.

Comment: @RikPoggi please look at the edited part, i am trying for the list of that type

Comment: @sum2000: You should've stated that from the beginning :) Anyway just iterate over your list_of_list and apply the method above on each sub list.

Answer (score 3):

I would create a generator to do it:

```
def intify(lst):
    for i in lst:
        try:
            i = int(i)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        yield i

lst = ['sam','1','dad','21']
intified_list = list(intify(lst))
# or if you want to modify an existing list
# lst[:] = intify(lst)
```

If you want this to work on a list of lists, just:

```
new_list_of_lists = map(list, map(intify, list_of_lists))
```

Comment: The idea is right, but the implementation is not very elegant; the `str`-to-`int` conversion and iteration should really be separated as in Rik Poggi's answer.

Comment: @larsmans I disagree. I assumed based on the question that this is only going to be used on sequences, so why require the extra step of `map`? Not everything has to be written in functional programming style. (Also, purely as a bonus, this gives the same result on both Python 2 and Python 3).

Comment: `map` is not needed, but separating iteration from purely per-element conversions, in my experience, leads to much cleaner and more readable code. It's a matter of [separating concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), not my FP fetish ;)

Comment: @sum2000 I already updated mine to match. The same basic idea could be used for the other answers.

Comment: @agf i tried but only first two intable strings of sublist 1 is converted to int

Comment: @sum2000 Post an example that doesn't work. I can't just guess what it is you want.

Answer (score 3):

How about using map and lambda

```
>>> map(lambda x:int(x) if x.isdigit() else x,['sam','1','dad','21'])
['sam', 1, 'dad', 21]
```

or with List comprehension

```
>>> [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in ['sam','1','dad','21']]
['sam', 1, 'dad', 21]
>>>
```

As mentioned in the comment, as isdigit may not capture negative numbers, here is a refined condition to handle it notable a string is a number if its alphanumeric and not a alphabet :-)

```
>>> [int(x) if x.isalnum() and not x.isalpha() else x for x in ['sam','1','dad','21']]
['sam', 1, 'dad', 21]
```

Comment: `str.isdigit()` isn't the right test to see if `int()` will work, specifically when you can have negative values. Calling `int()` is the right test.

Comment: i am doing `l1=[int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in l]`, it is showing   error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isdigit'`

Comment: @sum2000 This method only works if all the items in the list are strings. It sounds like some of the items in your list aren't.

Comment: How is l defined? can you tell me the result of `[type(x) for x in l]`

Comment: Your updated version is still wrong for negative numbers. `'-21'.isalnum()` is `False`. Calling `int` and handling the error is the only simple solution that always works. Not everything needs to be a one-liner.

Comment: @agf: Hmm I agree. Let me stop here thinking beyond.

Comment: @Abhijit '[<type 'list'>, <type 'list'>, <type 'list'>, <type 'list'>, <type 'list'>, <type 'list'>, <type 'list'>]
'

Comment: @sum2000: It seems your list is not a list of integers but a bit complex for that. None of the methods mentioned in here will work. Please give the correct format of l. What is the result of `print l`

Comment: @Abhijit i have edited the question and list type is list within a list

Answer (score 1):

For multidimenson lists, use recursive technique may help.

```
from collections import Iterable
def intify(maybeLst):
    try:
        return int(maybeLst)
    except:
        if isinstance(maybeLst, Iterable) and not isinstance(lst, str):
            return [intify(i) for i in maybeLst] # here we call intify itself!
        else:
            return maybeLst

maybeLst = [[['sam', 2],'1'],['dad','21']]
print intify(maybeLst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) to check each character in the string to see if it is a digit.

Example:

```
mylist = ['foo', '3', 'bar', '9']
t = [ int(item) if item.isdigit() else item for item in mylist ] 
print(t)
```

Comment: See Thomas' comment on the other equivalent answer about why this can be wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't `"-1"` be able to convert to int?

Answer (score 0):

- Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to validate the numeracy of each list item.
- [`str.isnumeric`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) won't pass a negative sign

  - Use [`str.lstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) to remove the `-`, check `.isnumeric`, and convert to `int` if it is.
  - Alternatively, use [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) in place of `.isnumeric`.

### Keep all values in the list

```py
l = ['sam', '1', 'dad', '21', '-10']

t = [int(v) if v.lstrip('-').isnumeric() else v for v in l]

print(t)

>>> ['sam', 1, 'dad', 21, -10]
```

## Remove non-numeric values

```py
l = ['sam', '1', 'dad', '21', '-10']

t = [int(v) for v in t if v.lstrip('-').isnumeric()]

print(t)

>>> [1, 21, -10]
```

## Nested list

```py
l = [['aa', '2'], ['bb', '3'], ['sam', '1', 'dad', '21', '-10']]

t = [[int(v) if v.lstrip('-').isnumeric() else v for v in x] for x in l]

print(t)

>>> [['aa', 2], ['bb', 3], ['sam', 1, 'dad', 21, -10]]
```